# Change .bst to put the pages number at the end

Tags: bibtex

My question is simple, but I searched in vain for an answer. Right now, my bibliography style (.bst) gives the following result for an article :

**Baumgärtel Hans, « Julius Weisbach und die Einführung der neuen Markscheidekunst in die Praxis », Zeitschrift für Bergbau, Hüttenwesen und verwandteWissenschaften, 13 (1), pp. 371–377, 1961.**

I would like to have it with the pages number after the date, so this way :

Baumgärtel Hans, « Julius Weisbach und die Einführung der neuen Markscheidekunst in die Praxis », Zeitschrift für Bergbau, Hüttenwesen und verwandteWissenschaften, 13 (1), **1961, pp. 371–377.**

Here's the function, i've tried to work on it, but I really dont understand how it works :

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output new.block
  format.title quote "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$

    { format.vol.num.pages output } %
    { format.vol.num.eid output }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
}
{ format.article.crossref output.nonnull

  eid empty$
    { format.pages output }
    { format.eid output }
  if$
}
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

If you can help me, thanks very much in advance ...
Thomas

List of all used packages :

```
\usepackage{appendix} \usepackage{bredele} % Appel de bredele.sty %\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib} %\usepackage{bibtopics} \usepackage[round]{natbib} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} % pour virer les espaces dans les environnements equation et alig\usepackage{etoolbox} % it\usepackage{array} \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % pour coller les notes en bas de page \usepackage{array} % pour centrer verticalement dans les tableaux \usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % un peu superflu, pour tenter d'améliorer l'hyphenation 
\usepackage{lmodern} % un peu superflu, pour tenter d'améliorer l'hyphenation 
\usepackage{index} % pour l'index 
\usepackage{splitidx} % REMPLACE 
\usepackage{multind}  %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % NEW %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % NEW 
\usepackage{colortbl}% pour les lignes en gris %
\usepackage{etoolbox} % pour utiliser \BeforeBeginEnvironment 
\usepackage{french}[babel] 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % mettre des cases de tableau en couleur %\usepackage{hyperref} % met des liens %
\usepackage{appendix} 
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{tikz} % pour des diagrammes simples 
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % pour mettre de grandes marges sur les pages d'annexes \usepackage{enumitem} \setlist{nolistsep} 
\usepackage{framed} % pour mettre des textes dans des boites
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't really see what kind of MWE ... its actually my thesis so that I have many packages ... but I'm pretty sure this only has to do with bibtex ! There should be a function where pages number are at the end of the reference ...

Comment: Your documentclass and your bst-file is important. unless you don't want to switch to `biblatex`.

Comment: You'll need to modify the BibTeX functions `format.vol.num.pages` and `format.vol.num.eid`. In those functions, you'll need to insert the line `format.date "year" output.check` between the code that typesets the article's volume and number data and the article's page data. Then, remove the line `format.date "year" output.check` from the function `article`. Without information about which `bst` file you're using, more specific advice isn't possible, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, so my document file is "book", my .bst file is "abbrvnat". I will try to put all the packages I used in the question above

Comment: May I ask why you opted for `@book` and not for `@inbook`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373777/9075

Answer (score 1):

Save the orignal file `abbrvnat.bst` in your working directory and rename it to eg. `mod-abbrvnat.bst`

Now you have to modify two functions: `format.vol.num.pages` and `article`:

Here the modifications:

- line 535

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
  { volume field.or.null
    number empty$
      'skip$
      { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
        volume empty$
          { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
          'skip$
        if$
      }
    if$
    format.date "year" output.check %<-new
    pages empty$
      'skip$
      { duplicate$ empty$
          { pop$ format.pages }
          { ", \penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }%<-comma new, old :
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
  ```
- line 700

  ```
  FUNCTION {article}
  { output.bibitem
    format.authors "author" output.check
    author format.key output
    new.block
    format.title "title" output.check
    new.block
    crossref missing$
      { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
        eid empty$
          { format.vol.num.pages output }
          { format.vol.num.eid output }
        if$
  %      format.date "year" output.check%<commented
      }
      { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
        eid empty$
          { format.pages output }
          { format.eid output }
        if$
      }
    if$
    format.issn output
    format.doi output
    format.url output
    new.block
    note output
    fin.entry
  }
  ```

After this modification the following mwe provides:

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Baumgaertel,
 title={Julius Weisbach und die Einführung der neuen Markscheidekunst in die Praxis},
 author={Baumgärtel, Hans},
 journal="Zeitschrift für Bergbau, Hüttenwesen und verwandteWissenschaften",
 volume={13},
 number={1},
 pages={pp~371 -- 377},
 year={1961} 
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{Baumgaertel}

\bibliographystyle{mod-abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Please note that more modifications are needed for other cases. I recommend the usage of `biblatex`.