# How to add page numbers to book related bibliographic entries?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, page-numbering

I am not an expert in Latex and am preparing a manuscript to submit to the **journal of the acoustical society of America**.

Here's an example entry of the **.bib** file:

```
@BOOK{Allard+2009,
 author = {Jean Allard and Noureddine Atalla},
 title = {Propagation of Sound in Porous Media},
 publisher = "John Wiley and Sons",
 year      =  2009,
 address   = "Chichester",
 pages = {72-89},
 edition   = "second"
}
```

When I use their **jasanum.bst** file using `\bibliographystyle{jasanum}`, it formats the bibliography nicelly however, it doesn't place the `pp. 72-89.`at the end of the bibliographic entry.

How do I add page numbers to book related bibliographic entries?

Comment: If your journal wants to have page numbers there then the bibliography driver will probably print them. Are you sure they are wanted?

Answer (score 23):

Try using `@inbook` instead of `@book`.

The **.bst** file of this journal has several definitions for citing books. When using `@book` in your **.bib** file you are implying that you are citing the whole book, and therefore there is no need for page numbers. When using `@inbook` you mean to say that you are citing a certain part of the book.
If you use `@inbook` the bibliography will show both pages and chapter of the book you are citing.

```
@INBOOK{inbookcite,
 author = {Jean Allard and Noureddine Atalla},
 title = {Propagation of Sound in Porous Media},
 publisher = "John Wiley and Sons",
 year      =  2009,
 address   = "Chichester",
 pages = {72-89},
 edition   = "second"
}

@BOOK{bookcite,
 author = {Jean Allard and Noureddine Atalla},
 title = {Propagation of Sound in Porous Media},
 publisher = "John Wiley and Sons",
 year      =  2009,
 address   = "Chichester",
 pages = {72-89},
 edition   = "second"
}
```

And the MWE (which I had to produce because OP did not)

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, amssymb, preprint, showpacs]{revtex4-1} 

\bibliographystyle{jasanum}


\begin{document}
bar \cite{bookcite} foo \citep{inbookcite}


\bibliography{foo}


\end{document}
```

The result is the following:
[image: Result]

The page numbers are shown, it is advised to add a chapter as this is the journal's style.

pp. is not printed before the page numbers, this is, again, due to the journals style. If OP wishes to change that he can edit **jasanum.bst**

Comment: Though short, this is an answer to the question. I have made it longer to explain WHY it is the answer to the question

Comment: Can you add code showing how to use this entry and a sample of the output.

Comment: It does not work. It does not place the ''pp. 72-89.'' at the end of the bibliographic entry. Please attach some code!

Comment: I added a code correcting the one you posted, if you add a MWE I could see why it does not work.

Comment: Also added a MWE though I really shouldn't have

Comment: There is also ....a continue bonus :-)