# Why is the `numpages` field not showing up in my LaTeX document, and how can I fix this?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I have a bibtex entry that includes a `numpages` field, like this:

```
@article{dummy-article,
  author = {Author1, Author2 and Author3},
  title = {Dummy Title},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Dummy Publisher},
  journal = {Dummy Journal},
  numpages = {39}
}
```

However, when I compile my LaTeX document, the `numpages` field is not showing up in the bibliography.

How can I fix this problem and get the `numpages` field to display correctly?

I have:

```
"\markright{\it Bibliography}
\begin{spacing}{0.1}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{[anonymized]}
\end{spacing}"
```

I also tried with changing the line `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain}` in my LaTeX document.

Comment: how or if a field is used depends on the bibtex style you have specified.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updated question.

Comment: Not a lot of BibTeX styles appear to support a `numpages` field. A quick search suggests `ACM-Reference-Format` does, as do styles of the `chembst` family as well as `apsrev` and `apsrmp` from RevTeX. I might have missed a few that do, but most other styles will not support this field.

Comment: In most cases the number of pages of an article or book is probably not very relevant. In the olden days you could read off the number of pages of an article by subtracting the start from the end page in the `pages` field. Is there any particular reason why you need to show `numpages`?

Comment: my professor told me to add num pages.

Comment: As already commented by @moewe BibTeX itself doesn't know anything about bibliography types (article, book, etc.) or the type entry fields (author, title, etc.) - everything is defined by the used .bst BibTeX style file.  Many .bst styles support the use of the `pages` field, e.g. `pages = {42-49}`. If it doesn't appear, check which entry types support pages because it usually makes sense only for `@inbook`, `@inproceedings`, `@article` and similar as part of a large entity.

Comment: See also question [How to add page numbers to book related bibliographic entries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373754).